# BERT Fine tuning: High loss and low accuracy in multiclass classification

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, pytorch-lightning

while binary classification with a finetuned Bert worked well, I am stuck with the multiclass classification. My dataset (german news articles, with 10 classes) contains roughly 10.000 samples.
Although, training loss and average evaluation loss circle around 2.2.

Some NLP config variables:

```
DEBUG=True
VERSION = 1
MAX_LEN = 200 #Set the maximum length according to the diagram above
BATCH_SIZE = 16
EPOCHS = 3
LEARNING_RATE = 2e-4
MOMENTUM = 0.9
TRAIN_SIZE = 0.7
NUM_LABELS = len(df_data.Labels.unique())
MODEL_NAME = "dbmdz/bert-base-german-cased"
params = {"debug": DEBUG, "max_len": MAX_LEN, "batch_size": BATCH_SIZE, "epochs": EPOCHS, "lr": LEARNING_RATE, "momentum": MOMENTUM, "model": MODEL_NAME, "loss": "BCEWithLogitsLoss", "optimizer": "SGD"}
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
```

The DataLoader:

```
class NLPDataset(th.utils.data.Dataset):

  def __init__(self, dataframe, tokenizer, max_len):
    self.tokenizer = tokenizer
    self.max_len = max_len
    self.data = dataframe
    self.text = dataframe.Text
    self.targets = dataframe.Labels
    self.len = len(self.text)

  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    text = str(self.text[idx])
    text = " ".join(text.split())

    inputs = self.tokenizer(
        text,
        None,
        add_special_tokens=True,
        max_length=self.max_len,
        pad_to_max_length=True,
        return_token_type_ids=True,
        truncation=True,
        padding='max_length',
    )
    input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
    mask = inputs['attention_mask']
    token_type_ids = inputs["token_type_ids"]

    return {
        'input_ids': th.tensor(input_ids, dtype=th.long),
        'mask': th.tensor(mask, dtype=th.float),
        'token_type_ids': th.tensor(token_type_ids, dtype=th.long),
        'targets': th.tensor(self.targets[idx], dtype=th.long)
    }
  
  def __len__(self):
    return self.len
```

The Pytorch_lightning Module:

```
class NLPClassifier(pl.LightningModule):

  def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

      #changing the configuration to 10 lables instead of 2
      config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)
      config.num_labels = NUM_LABELS
      self.model = transformers.AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_config(config)
      self.loss = th.nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction="none")

  def prepare_data(self):
      # train/val split
      train_dataset = df_data.sample(frac=TRAIN_SIZE)
      val_dataset=df_data.drop(train_dataset.index).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
      train_dataset = train_dataset.reset_index(drop=True)

      # Assign CustomDataset Class
      train_set = NLPDataset(train_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)
      val_set = NLPDataset(val_dataset, tokenizer, MAX_LEN)

      print("FULL Dataset: {}".format(df_data.shape))
      print("TRAIN Dataset: {}".format(train_dataset.shape))
      print("VAL Dataset: {}".format(val_dataset.shape))

      # assign to use in dataloaders
      self.train_ds = train_set
      self.val_ds = val_set
      #self.test_dataset = mnist_test DO TO
  
  def forward(self, input_ids, mask):
      logits, = self.model(input_ids, mask)
      # logits.shape: (16, 10)
      return logits
  
  def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self.forward(batch['input_ids'], batch['mask']).squeeze()
    loss = self.loss(logits, batch['targets']).mean()
    run.log(name='train_loss', value=loss.tolist())
    return {'loss': loss, 'log': {'train_loss': loss}}
  
  def validation_step(self,batch, batch_idx):
    logits = self.forward(batch['input_ids'], batch['mask']).squeeze()
    print(logits.shape)
    acc = (logits.argmax(-1) == batch['targets']).float()
    loss = self.loss(logits, batch['targets'])
    run.log_list('loss', loss.tolist())
    run.log_list('acc', acc.tolist())
    return {'loss': loss, 'acc': acc}

  def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
    loss = th.cat([o['loss'] for o in outputs], 0).mean()
    acc = th.cat([o['acc'] for o in outputs], 0).mean()
    out = {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}
    run.log('val_loss', loss.tolist())
    run.log('val_acc', acc.tolist())
    return {**out, 'log': {'val_loss': loss, 'val_acc': acc}}
    
  def train_dataloader(self):
      return th.utils.data.DataLoader(
          self.train_ds,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          num_workers=8,
          drop_last=True,
          shuffle=False,
      )
  
  def val_dataloader(self):
      return th.utils.data.DataLoader(
          self.val_ds,
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          num_workers=8,
          drop_last=False,
          shuffle=False,
      )

  
  def configure_optimizers(self):
      return transformers.AdamW(
            self.model.parameters(),
            lr=LEARNING_RATE,
            #momentum=MOMENTUM,
        )
```

The trainer:

```
model = NLPClassifier()
trainer = pl.Trainer(
   gpus=(1 if th.cuda.is_available() else 0),
   default_root_dir = f"./models/version_{VERSION}",
   max_epochs=EPOCHS,
   fast_dev_run=DEBUG,
   limit_train_batches=1.0,
   val_check_interval=0.5,
   limit_val_batches=1.0,
   profiler=True,
   #logger=wandb_logger
   )
```

trainer.fit(model)

This is a sample loss curve.

[Sample loss curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MvH7.png)

My central questions are:

1. Is CrossEntropyLoss correctly used?
2. Does the optimizer work, as the predictions fairly quickly become the same for every sample.
3. The learning rate issue did not solve the problem. I tried a range from 1e-2 to 1e-6

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Did you follow example code to build the `NLPDataset` class? If so, what code?

Comment: Originally I used one of hugging face‘s sample notebooks like Multiclass Distilbert finetuning. https://colab.research.google.com/github/abhimishra91/transformers-tutorials/blob/master/transformers_multiclass_classification.ipynb

Comment: Are you sure this line is correct: `inputs = self.tokenizer(text, ...)` ? I'm only familiar with the BERT tokenizer, but my educated guess is that the line should be `inputs = self.tokenizer.encode_plus(...)` .

Comment: You are right, transformers used to have the encode_plus and batch_encode_plus methods but with their new version 3.0.0 you can call the tokenizer directly. https://huggingface.co/transformers/preprocessing.html
so it should and it does return the same as encode_plus. Namely input_ids, attention_masks and token_type_ids.